# When making model1_model2 tables, do I create a model or?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a users table, and a roles table.

I want to make a table like:

```
model1_model2
```

with columns:

```
model1_id
model2_id
other_column int
other_column2 int
```

Since I need to expose those other columns (other than id's), do I just make a model that matches this table and call it `Module1Module2`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're looking for the [`has_and_belongs_to_many` relationship](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has_and_belongs_to_many-association).

You shouldn't be putting information in a join table unless it describes the relationship between the two models, in which case `has_and_belongs_to_many` does not apply and you must make a model specifically for the relation.

Answer (score 1):

Pretty much..
This is an excelent resource with exactly what you're looking for:
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has_many-through-association